# How to move the class, when the registration is successful at android AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, android-asynctask

on `onPostExecute` I get results `{"STATUS": true}` if I managed to input the data, `{"STATUS": false}` if the input fails.

I want to make if `{"STATUS": true}` then move to the `LoginActivity` class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

if `{"STATUS": false}` then move to the RegisterActivity class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

how the source code should I write and put where ?

Here is the code AsynTask.

```
private void registerNewMember(){

    // Ubah setiap View EditText ke tipe Data String
    final String memberId = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String phoneType = mPhoneType.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String name = mNamaPengguna.getText().toString().trim();
    final String pwd = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    // Pembuatan Class AsyncTask yang berfungsi untuk koneksi ke Database Server
    class registerNewMember extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        String res;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "Registering Account...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();

            // Sesuaikan bagian ini dengan field di tabel
            params.put(KEY_MEMBER_ID, memberId);
            params.put(KEY_PHONE_TYPE, phoneType);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            params.put(KEY_PWD, pwd);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            res = rh.sendPostRequest(GlobalVariabel.URL_REGISTER_NEW_MEMBER, params);
            Log.d("info", res.toString());
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    // Jadikan Class registerNewMember Sabagai Object Baru
    registerNewMember register = new registerNewMember();
    register.execute();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "move a class"?

Comment: I guess you are already redirecting to Login page on  {"STATUS":true}.
Also is the method registerNewMember() within your activity?

Comment: @Stultuske yes move a login activity class at on PostExecute

Comment: @AndroidMason yes, I've been putting registerNewMember() in the login button at my Activity. but when I execute successfully, the results are not moving to LoginActivity class

Comment: @Drians do you get any error? or do you want to pass data along with redirecting your activity? your query isn't very clear.

Comment: @AndroidMason i didn`t get error, I want when I managed to input data to the server, the class will move to the login Activity class, when it failed to keep the Register class Activity. 
if(s.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

Comment: @Drians did you try ?
{ Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class); startActivity(intent); }

Comment: @AndroidMasson the result remains the same, unsuccessful move to class LoginActivity :D

Comment: @Drians kindly share your code for LoginActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(s.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
              Intent intent =new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
                   new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this)
                       .setTitle("ProjectName")
                       .setMessage("Your Message")
                       .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                             mUsername.setText("");
                             mPhoneType.setText("");
                             mEmail.setText("");
                             mNamaPengguna.setText("");
                             mPassword.setText("");

                             dialog.dismiss();
                             }
                         })
                      .show();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this answer by [**@Samuh**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

One option could be letting your custom class implement the Serializable interface and then you can pass object instances in the intent extra using the putExtra(Serializable..) variant of the Intent#putExtra() method.

```
//To pass:
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);

// To retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```